# making a div non refreshable in jsp (without using AJAX)

Tags: javascript, html, css, jsp

On my JSP page with multiple div tags, of which I want to make a particular div non refreshable so that it retains its value when the jsp submits a form to servlet.

I am loosing div data as soon as the form is submitted to upload files.

How to do this without using ajax?

I've searched a lot but only could find ways to make a div refreshable.

In my below JSP page code, the form myform is submitted to upload.java and is redirected back to this jsp page. Now, I don't want to loose the contents of box div.

My JSP page

```
<div id="box">${f1stat}<br>${f2stat}<br>${f3stat}</div>

<div  style="position: absolute; right: -5%; top: 2%;">
<form method="post" name="myform" action="upload" enctype="multipart/form-data">
Left File :  <input type="file" name="dataFile1" id="fileChooser1" />
Right File : <input type="file" name="dataFile2" id="fileChooser2" />
Config File :<input type="file" name="dataFile3" id="fileChooser3" />
Geco File :  <input type="file" name="dataFile4" id="fileChooser4" />
<input type="hidden" id="myField" value="" />
<button type="button" id="execute" onclick="ValidateFile()">Click to Upload files</button>
<button type= "button" id="execute" onclick="saveTextAsFile()">Click to execute</button>
</form>
</div>
```

the box div is populated during execution by commands like

```
var err1 = document.getElementById("box");
err1.innerHTML = err1.innerHTML + "<br>" + "<span class='red'>Configuration file and Geco script should not be the same as left or right files. Please check your uploads</span>";
```

I am using the box div like a console display

Servlet redirecting by

```
RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("geco.jsp");
rd.forward(request, response);
```

Comment: what do you mean by non refreshable? When the user refreshes the page all not persisted data will be lost. You will have to store changes in a db or local storage and re-apply those on reload.

Comment: I have a form and div on my page, when the form is submitted to servlet I don't want to loose div data.

Comment: The action against what the form is submitted - is this on the same URL where the form itself(with this div) is? Or after processign the form submit is user redirected to the original form page but the content in div has changed meanwhile? If that is the case then you need to be more specific. What is in the div before submit? What after submit?

Comment: The URL which handles upload is a different one and is redirected to this on on a forward response type.

Comment: OK. So you end up in the original page. In that case. What is there in your div before submit and what is there after submit?

Comment: My div before consisted of messages, actually I am using this div as a console log to display exception and success messages so I don't want to loose this history.

Comment: Then put those message into the session; or embedded them into the form you are submitting as hidden fields, so that they will get send to the “next” page explicitly.

Comment: How can this data go along with the form and come back with response?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What comes to mind is saving the data on first load into a session scoped variable, then checking if that variable has a value on subsequent loads before setting it. That way your value will be retained:

```
<c:if test="${empty test}">
    <c:set var="test" value="${objectWithData}" scope="session" />
</c:if>
```

Then use the properties of the object saved in the `var` to display info in your div.